# How to get vim-haskellmode and cabal-dev working together?

Tags: haskell, vim

I'm using the [haskellmode-vim](https://github.com/lukerandall/haskellmode-vim) plugin. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work very well with cabal-dev (apparently it invokes GHC directly). Now I'm wondering if there's some way to get haskellmode to work in a project managed by cabal-dev (ideally, without a lot of project specific setup?). Searching for this I only found something pointing at ghcmod, and I'm not really sure how that'd help in this case.

Comment: There is also `cabal sandbox`, you could give it a try. And you could try  to start vim inside of the cabal project.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out for myself with some considerable help from `#haskell` on freenode.

In your .vimrc you should have the following lines (probably already if you have hdevtools and cabal-dev setup)

Taken from http://lpaste.net/94999 original author unknown.  Slightly edited here to remove a deprecation warning.

```
function! FindCabalSandboxRoot()
    return finddir('.cabal-sandbox', './;')
endfunction

function! FindCabalSandboxRootPackageConf()
    return glob(FindCabalSandboxRoot().'/*-packages.conf.d')
endfunction

let g:hdevtools_options = '-g-ilib -g-isrc -g-i. -g-idist/build/autogen -g-Wall -g-package-db='.FindCabalSandboxRootPackageConf()
```

The documentation of haskellmode-vim recommends the following lines in your `.vimrc`:

```
au Bufenter *.hs compiler ghc
```

Reading the haskellmode-vim plugin source, the options to ghc are stored in a buffer variable called ghc_staticoptions, so now we know everything we need to know to make cabal-dev work.

```
au Bufenter *.hs let b:ghc_staticoptions = '-ilib -isrc -i. -idist/build/autogen -Wall -package-db='.FindCabalSandboxRootPackageConf()
```

However, as mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622390/is-haskellmode-vim-dead?rq=1) haskellmode-vim is not quite dead but resting.  So you may want to look into a different plugin.